# all points y value undefined and the syntax of "using" modifier

Tags: gnuplot, nan, conditional-operator

I came across an unexpected Gnuplot behaviour (Version 5.2 patchlevel 6) I could not explain, so far.
This is the data (though any similar data would do):

```
x   y
0   1.1
1   1.0
2   1.3
3   1.4
4   0.9
```

The line

```
p a=0 'data.txt'  u 1:(a=a+$2,a) w lp
```

works perfectly: plots the progressive summation of column 2 and stores the partial sum in “a” (this is a simple, almost naive, way of integrating column 2).

```
pr a
```

returns 5.7, which is the expected value. But let us change the code a bit.

1. Using an expression at left side of the colon.

The line

```
p a=0 'data.txt'  u (a=a+$2,$1):2 w lp
```

simply plots columns 1 and 2 and it works, but

```
pr a
```

Returns NaN. What is wrong in this case, since the summation process is nearly the same?

2. Enclosing the left side of the colon in parenthesis.

This one

```
p a=0 'data.txt'  u ($1):(a=a+$2,a) w lp
```

returns “all points y value undefined!”. Why, since the syntax seems right?

3. More complicated expressions

The origin of this problem was this line:

```
p a=0 'data.txt' u ($1>1 && $1<4? $1:1/0):(a=$2+a,a) w lp
```

which returns “all points y value undefined!” (I was trying to integrate column 2 in the xrange from 1 to 4). Nonetheless, the following works nicely (it is almost the same as before, but plots the column 2 instead "a")

```
p a=0 'data.txt' u ($1>1 && $1<4? $1:1/0):(a=$2+a,$2) w lp
```

However, “a” returns NaN again.

Finally, the following is the way to make it work perfectly, though it simply moves the ternary operator to the right side of the colon.

```
p a=0 'data.txt' u 1:($1>1 && $1<4? a=$2+a: 1/0,a) w lp
```

I am pretty sure all of this has a single cause, which I hope to be my poor understanding of the syntax, instead of a bug.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I have always used the abbreviated form of the commands. So I hope the code is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this behaviour not just for gnuplot 5.2.6 but also for newer versions.

I guess there are a few things which might not be obvious and/or need to be known:

- `a + NaN = NaN` and `NaN + a = NaN`
- `plot FILE u ($1):2` might behave differently in some cases compared to `plot FILE u 1:2`

Let's have a look at your commands:

1. `plot a=0 'data.txt'  u 1:(a=a+$2,a) w lp`

- works as expected, actually `(a=a+$2)` would be sufficient.
  The very first line will be ignored because for plotting, column 1 will be evaluated as `NaN`, hence not plotted and the rest of the line apparently will be ignored. Nothing will be added to `a`, i.e. still `a=0`. But the values of the following lines of column 2 will be added and give the expected result.

2. `plot a=0 'data.txt'  u (a=a+$2,$1):2 w lp`

- first row, second column is `y`. The string `'y'` interpreted as floating point number gives `NaN`. `a+NaN=NaN`. So, `a` will get and stay `NaN`.

3. `plot a=0 'data.txt'  u ($1):(a=a+$2,a) w lp`

- my suspicion to explain the behaviour: `($1)` is also interpreted as `NaN` and not plotted, but it seems the rest of the line is evaluated nevertheless. Hence, `a` + `'y'` gets again `NaN` and `a=NaN` stays for the rest.

4. `plot a=0 'data.txt' u ($1>1 && $1<4? $1:1/0):(a=$2+a,a) w lp`

- same like 3.

5. `plot a=0 'data.txt' u ($1>1 && $1<4? $1:1/0):(a=$2+a,$2) w lp`

- for the very first line `$2` is interpreted as `NaN` and `NaN` is simply not plotted, but the rest of column 2 is plotted.

6. `plot a=0 'data.txt' u 1:($1>1 && $1<4? a=$2+a: 1/0,a) w lp`

- same like 1.

**Possible solutions:**

1. remove or comment out your first line, i.e. `#  x   y` in your data
2. or skip the first line `plot FILE u 1:2 skip 1`
3. or use the first line as columnheader `plot FILE u 1:2 ti columnhead`

Comment: Different behaviors of `using 1` and `using ($1)` were a bug/misfeature that was supposedly fixed in the transition from  gnuplot version 4 to version 5. But yes there may have been some corner cases that lingered as bugs as late as version 5.2.  In many cases the command `set datafile missing NaN` was sufficient to hide any inconsistency.  I think it would work in the case here.